# JQuery & Meteor Class Manipulation

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I have a list of documents (todos) displayed by Meteor using an {{#each}} block.  Each todo list item uses it's Document ID as the HTML Element ID.  I am trying to use JQuery to modify the class structure on click.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="todos">
    {{#each todos}}
        <li id={{_id}} class="todo">{{description}} ({{complete}})</li>
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

When a user clicks on the item, I trigger a Template.Event to mark the document "complete" in Mongo.  I would also like to toggle the class to "completed" and change the styling.  Here is my Coffee Code:

```
'click .todo': () ->
    self = this
    if Todos.findOne({_id: this._id}).complete is false
        Todos.update({_id: this._id}, { $set: {complete: true}})
    else
        Todos.update({_id: this._id}, { $set: {complete: false}})
    $("##{this._id}").toggleClass("completed")
```

I have validated that I am getting the right JQuery object back, but for some reason I can't manipulate the class.  I also tried using addClass without luck.  I am wondering if there is some Meteor re-rendeding going on that may be causing me issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you start using Meteor, you have to do certain things the Meteor way.

To solve your issue, start adding a "complete" helper in the template HTML :

```
<div class="todos">
    {{#each todos}}
        <li id={{_id}} class="todo {{complete}}">{{description}} ({{complete}})</li>
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

This template definition is straightforward, you simply return the appropriate class according to the value of the underlying data context which is actually the model (note : we're using the same name - overloading, sort of - the default complete helper which simply returns the VALUE of the data context).

```
Template.todos.complete=function(){
    return this.complete?"completed":"";
}
```

Then in the event part, just update the model :

```
"click .todo":function(event,template){
    var complete=template.data.complete;
    Todos.update(template.data._id,{$set:{complete:!complete}});
}
```

This should work as expected.

Apart from defining your own reactive contexts, the two main reactive data sources in Meteor are collections and Session variables.
When you modify the DOM out of Meteor templating system using jQuery, the current Meteor rendering engine unfortunately wipes out your modifications every time it re-renders so the best solution is to use helpers, because Meteor engine is obviously aware of them.

You're right about Meteor UI solving your issue, because the new engine will be smarter and won't clear your DOM class attributes, but I think this approach is even simpler than having to rely on jQuery to perform a simple class toggle, although it's the traditional way of doing things from a front-end perspective.

Answer (score 1):

I did a bit of research and it looks like {{#constant}} region is the best answer so far given how Meteor renders.  It works OK, but it still has issues.  The benefit is that the styling changes to the DOM work, but the downside is the data inside the element is no longer reactive (even though the changes do take place in the database).  Hopefully the new Meteor UI work addresses this.

Here is the code that allowed my DOM styling to take effect:

```
    <div class="todos">
        {{#each todos}}
            {{#constant}}
                <li id={{_id}} class="todo">{{description}}</li>
            {{/constant}}
        {{/each}}
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use jQuery for simple class manipulation - do it directly from the template:

```
<template name="todos">
  {{#each todos}}
    {{>todo}}
  {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="todo">
  <li id="{{_id}}" class="todo {{status}}">{{description}} ({{complete}})</li>
</template>
```

Then in your coffeescript:

```
Template.todo.status = -> if @complete then "complete" else "incomplete"

Template.todo.events
  'click .todo': ->
    Todos.update {_id: @_id}, {$set: {complete: !@complete}}
```